# Are there performance downsides while using autoloading classes in PHP?

Tags: php, class, autoload

Currently I load in all my classes by including a "all.inc.php" file on every page of my site, this file then goes on to include all the config, classes, functions, etc. that I will use on the whole site.

My issue with this is that often I use classes that only pertain to certain pages/sections of a website, so often I am including a bunch of classes at the start of the page which will not be used.

Obviously autoloading the classes would fix this issue, so my question is, would autoloading the classes give me a performace downside as the server then has to check if a file exists? And if there is a downside, then is this downside worse than having to include a number of classes that may not get used on the page? Or is the difference negatable?

Comment: Just use `require()`, which will be better on performance as well as it does not have to check if it is unique.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This article has some information and benchmarks: [PHP autoload performance (archived)](https://web.archive.org/web/20160610044931/https://athos.blogs.balabit.com/2011/03/php-autoload-performance/). Conclusion:

> Autoloading does not significantly degrade performance. Include_path lookup, reading and parsing PHP scripts from disk takes much longer time than that bare autoloading logic costs.

Comment: Thanks, that article was the kind of explanation I was looking for!

Comment: Short answer: not really (it's a tiny performance hit), no, and yes :)

Comment: Link broken. :(

Comment: added link to archived version

Answer (score 6):

Autoloading a class is almost as fast as including the class in the normal way. Switching to autoloading will improve performance in your case, because PHP loads less files and classes.

Comment: While the ethos of this is correct, it depends on the code base. If your code base is tightly coupled, and classes rely on each other, there may be no benefit to autoloading, as most (or all) of the classes may get loaded anyways. Just a thought ;-)

Answer (score 3):

Autoloading will improve the performance if the script does not have to search the files each time in the filesystem. If you use namespaces you can have a nice mapping of the namespace and class name to a folder and file like Some/Nice/ClassName would map to Some/Nice/ClassName.php.

If you do not use namespaces and have to search through folders I suggest you to create a custom singleton class to include files that allows you to do something like:

App::uses('Some/Nice', 'ClassName');

In Autoload use the registered path and class name to map it to a path and file combining both args from the uses method in my example. This will allow you some namespace like functionality for class loading until you're ready to change your app to use namespaces.

Answer (score 2):

You should use autoloading with cache index of all available classes/files in project.

Example:

```
$class_cache=array(
    'MyClass'=>'lib/MyClass.php',
    'Item'=>'model/Item.php'
);

function __autoload($class_name) {
 if(array_key_exists($class_name))
   include $class_cache[$class_name];
 else
   throw new Exception("Unable to load $class_name.");
}
```

You need to keep class list actual or write some generator for $class_cache.

Comment: Thanks for the example code, but all my classes follow the same naming convention and will match up using the class name pretty easily, so I don't think an array to match them up is the best solution. I'm now certain that I'm going to use autoload though! So thanks to you (and the others) for the explanations.

Comment: Ok, but if you write auto-generator for $class_cache and run it before deploy You will check disk for available php files only once at deploy process, not on every request.

Answer (score 1):

Each `include()` and `require()` (and their `_once`siblings) carry a performance penalty on their own. Disk seeks and reads also come at a cost. It really depends on your code, if you are loading 20 classes but use only 2 or 3 at any single point, then it's definitely worth going the autoloading route.

If performance is your main concern, you should look into merging your class files into a single file and instantiate what you need.

Comment: Throwing tons of classes into a single file is pretty bad practice.

Comment: @burzum and why would that be?

Comment: Separation of concerns is not really about putting a bunch of classes into separate files vs putting multiple classes in one file. I assume that, following the same logic, merging JS or CSS files is also a pretty bad practice?

Comment: @burzum I'd only recommend that if you have a build compiler that concatenates all development files into one. While you're at that, might as well strip whitespace and comments, too! Yii does this, and provides a YiiLite.php: http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/1.1/en/topics.performance#using-x-9x

Comment: @code_burgar I'm well aware of this. Minifying is done for a different purpose. Or are you now going to tell me you *work* with the minified code...? One file per class is simply good practice, logical and yes,  kind of separation of concerns.

Answer (score 1):

A really old question, but all the answers were actually wrong.

> ... autoloading takes a significant amount of resources. The number varies a lot and that’s maybe not what you’ve seen in your own app, but a typical 10% wouldn’t be surprising.

from CTO of Blackfire.io, so I'm sure he knows what he is talking about. Read more [here](https://blog.blackfire.io/speeding-up-autoloading-on-php-5-6-7-0-for-everyone.html)