# Is performance affected if all files are included in project?

Tags: php, performance

So, if for example, I have this directory structure with some example files:

```
/app
- /Modules
- /Core
    - Router.php
- /Library
    - Hooks.php
    - Autoloader.php
- /Controllers
- /Models
```

...how badly would loading every single file with an autoloader affect performance so that all classes are available simply with something as simple as `use MyProject\Library\ClassName`?

Comment: This other answered question may provide some direction http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8240726/are-there-performance-downsides-while-using-autoloading-classes-in-php

Comment: If you automatically include everything, then you're taking up a lot of memory, and memory allocation/deallocation is a big performance overhead; include only what is needed by the script that is executing, and the memory overhead is a lot lower, so less of that performance overhead.... with a decently written autoloader, you can even reduce the traditional autoloader overheads

Comment: @MichaelLeaCrawford thank you, this was helpful.

Comment: @MarkBaker thank you, this has given me a better insight on this.

Answer (score 0):

If you only include the necessary files, then using an autoloader will have very little affect on performance. If you find that you are including files when they don't get used, using an autoloader will boost performance.

See https://athos.blogs.balabit.com/2011/03/php-autoload-performance/ for benchmark of `autoloaders` vs `include_once` and `include`.